# Mysterious Padding

Tags: css, layout, html

This is a much-simplified version of a layout I'm working on. I've pared it down for berevity and to make the problem I'm having more apparent.

I cannot determine where the padding between elements wrapped in 'wrapper1' is coming from. Ideally I shouldn't be able to see any of the red from wrapper1's background and everything inside should be snug up against each other.

Any ideas?

**CSS**

```
.wrapper1 {
    float:left;
}

.wrapper2 {
    background-color:#F00;
}

.box-outer {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#09F;
    width:50px;
    height:108px;
}

.wrapper3 {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#390;
    border:2px solid #000;
}

.box-inner {
    background-color:#999;
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #FF0;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <div class="box-outer"></div>
        <div class="wrapper3">
            <div class="box-inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
        <div class="wrapper2">
        <div class="box-outer"></div>
        <div class="wrapper3">
            <div class="box-inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="wrapper2">
        <div class="box-outer"></div>
        <div class="wrapper3">
            <div class="box-inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unless you use a css reset, it comes from your browser.

Comment: @JanDragsbaek: What browser adds default padding to `<div>`?

Comment: as you can see in the answer, they get implicit padding (with the whitespace) because of inline-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mr. Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8757225/398242) is right that it's the white space giving you issues with `inline-block`.

Rather than have to fight this by removing white space from your markup...

Unless you have a compelling reason to use `inline-block`, it seems this layout works fine by replacing those instances with `float:left` (which in turn, implicitly applies `display:block`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yV89U/

Comment: +1 for simplifying. In his defense, he did say this example was a much-simplified version of his layout, so he may have a need for inline-block.

Comment: Yep, you're right - it might not be an option for the actual layout.

Answer (score 3):

You turned the inner divs into inline elements, which means that they will use the white space between them.

Write it like `...</div><div ...` and the gaps will go away.

Edit: oh, that's just the horizontal space taken care of. The vertical space is caused by the inner divs being positioned on the baseline and the outer div leaving room below the baseline. `vertical-align` should solve that.

Comment: Here's your version, looks fine to me after setting the `vertical-align`: http://jsfiddle.net/NPN3L/1/ The markup is sure a mess, but that's the price to pay I guess...

Comment: @MrLister You set Madmartigan on the path that solved my issue. I'm new to stackoverflow, so if there's a more appropriate way to give you kudos I haven't yet found it. Thanks again!

Comment: @RobJSchultz: When you get 15 rep you can upvote the answer, which is the proper way to "give kudos" here ;) Welcome to the site, stick around - quality members are rare sometimes. We appreciate your effort in your post and interaction with your answerers.